# Redirect to another page without history back log

Tags: javascript

I have a web page, which enable open page in a new tab(`_blank` open). We need to active browser back button after user go to new tab page and make user go to same page they come from in new tab.

**Example:** user click on A page, and go to new tab and open B page. When user click on back button of B page, we expect to open a same page with A page in B page tab. Also, B page is external page and I cannot do any change there. So I add a redirect page between A page and B page.

Although I use `window.location.href` to jump to new page in redirect page, redirect page still haven't got any log in history, and I cannot change history log by `pushStatus`. But when I have no meaning click on redirect page(simple click on the page), the redirect page will have history log as expected. Does anyone know the reason and tell me how to fix it ? Thank you.

**Redirect page code is as below:**

[image]

Comment: It is possible, but why would you want to do that? That's not how the history stack is supposed to work. The user can just go to the first tab.

Comment: @D.Pardal i think we have to manipulate history of the B tab. and have to push the a URL in the b tab

Comment: You would need to push A and then B (stack: A, B, A) so that when the user goes back, A appears. But then if the user went back again, B would appear.

Comment: Yes, but it is confused that I cannot add redirect page into history log, and cannot manipulate history in redirect page. But if user have any click on page(Not call by JavaScript), history can be manipulated and redirect page log will set as expected. Do you know why.